# Facebook and Twitter pages integration on libgdx android

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to set two simple buttons on the inicial screen of my app that open the facebook and twitter official sites of the app. Note I'm using libgdx. I created two siumple buttons, fb and tw.

I'm using this code in my Input Handler:

```
if (fb.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
    try {
        Gdx.net.openURI("fb://page/<page_id>");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Gdx.net.openURI("https://facebook.com/<page_name>");
    }
    return true;

}

if (tw.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
    try {
        Gdx.net.openURI("twitter://user?user_id=<user_id>");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Gdx.net.openURI("https://twitter.com/<user_name>");
    }
    return true;
}
```

If the android device has installed the official facebook and twitter apps, there is no problem, it opens well the correct pages on their respective apps, but if facebook and twitter apps are not installed, insted of opening the url with the default browser, the app crashes.

I don't know why is this happening, do you have some idea?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is from way back but I figured this might help someone as I was struggling with this exact issue.

The way I solved it:

```
if (!Gdx.net.openURI("fb://page/<page_id>")) { // opens app
    Gdx.net.openURI("https://facebook.com/<page_name>"); // opens site if app not installed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always have a long and flexible way to use some pure java/android SDK to have powerful options in social services integration. But you have to do (a lot of) work to integrate it and configure to your app through target platforms backends.
For example if you would like to support Facebook on Android build you will add [FB SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android) library to Android project and then [forward requests to your core project](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

- Facebook has official SDK for all popular platform ([here is one for Android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)).
- Twitter lack of official SDK, but there is [a list of some community implementations](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries). In case of Android, I would recommend you [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library.

But this is perhaps too much if only thing you need is just showing some page. So, please **provide us with some stacktrace on crash**.

Comment: The thing is that it does not catch the exception, never goes inside the catch bunch of code. I solved it by checking if the app is installed, but it is not what I wanted to do because I have lost the libgdx abstraction.